# Flash AS3 <-> PHP via POST failing outside of Flash Professional

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, post, http-post

After some researching, it seems this is a pretty popular problem. Unfortunately, none of the previously-answered questions have been able to solve this particular issue I am facing.

So, first things first, **The Setup:**

1. I have a personal web server, accessible externally via http, henceforth referred to as **the webserver**.
2. The webserver is capable of servicing php requests.
3. I have a php script, henceforth referred to as **the php**.
4. The php parses a POST request, and uses the data send to update a MySQL database, also hosted on the webserver, that is henceforth referred to as **the database**.
5. I use a *select* command on the webserver, connected to remotely using PuTTy, to check the rows that the php affects, in a process henceforth referred to as **checking for changes**.
6. I have a Flash project, created in Adobe Flash Professional CS6, using AS3, henceforth referred to as **the Flash**.
7. The Flash creates a POST request, sent to the php, in a process henceforth referred to as **the transmission**. The transmission is properly formatted, and has been vetted to make sure that it is being interpreted by the php correctly and is making the appropriate changes to the database.
8. The Flash is published with "Access network only" set. Changing it
   does not seem to make a difference, however.

Now with that being said, here is **The Code**.

Note that I have changed the url in the code below to point to a bogus web-server. I have also changed the database connection information to be similarly bogus. The rest of the structure is correct, however, including folder-structure and file-name:

**Flash (Code.DataTransmitter):**

```
public function SendData():void {
    var myData:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

    myData.update = "true";
    myData.score_humans = MasterManager.gameManager.scoreHumans;
    myData.score_creatures = MasterManager.gameManager.scoreCreatures;

    var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://not-a-real-web-server.com/data/testgame.php");

    myRequest.data = myData;
    myRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, OnSendDataComplete);

    try {
        loader.load(myRequest);
    } catch (error:Error) {
        trace ('Error: unable to load the document.');
    }
}

public function OnSendDataComplete(e:Event):void {
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $dbhost = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
    $dbuser = 'bogususer';
    $dbpass = 'boguspassword';

    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, 'test_game_table', 3306);

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") "  . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $score_humans = intval( $_POST['score_humans'] );
    $score_creatures = intval( $_POST['score_creatures'] );

    if ($score_humans >= 0 && $score_creatures >= 0) { // Error-check: No negative values
        $strquery = "update stats";

        $strquery .= " set score_humans = score_humans + " . $score_humans;
        $strquery .= ", score_creatures = score_creatures + " . score_creatures;

        $strquery .= " where id = 1";

        $strquery = $mysqli->real_escape_string($strquery); // Even though it should be clean, sanitize it anyways.

        $mysqli->query($strquery);

        echo "received=true";
    }
}

echo "Hello there!";

?>
```

And now, finally, **The Problem**.

It's really a simple problem, that probably doesn't deserve this much preamble, but I believe in getting all of the information out and disambiguated first, to reduce the amount of questions needed before solutions can be proposed.

1. When I run the Flash in Flash Professional, the database **is** properly
   updated - checking for changes correctly returns the changes that
   are being sent.
2. When I run the Flash (or more accurately, the published html
   wrapper) in Google Chrome on the hard-disk (being addressed with
   file:///), the database **is NOT** properly updated - checking for
   changes returns that no changes were made, when there should have
   been changes made.
3. When I run the Flash in Google Chrome, hosted from the same
   web-server as the php (more precisely, 
   *http://not-a-real-web-server.com/flash/test_game.html*), the database **is NOT** properly updated.

Put more concisely, the request **only** seems to work correctly when sent through Flash Professional - when sent through Google Chrome, it fails in some capacity.

I would really appreciate any assistance in solving this problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: does your web-service have crossdomain.xml file ?

Comment: Well, 2. is the result of security sandboxing. Not sure about 1 & 3 though.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a crossdomain.xml issue as I ran into something like this years ago.

Comment: If you put it on the same server, actually, on the same **domain**, there must not be a problem and you don't need the crossdomain policy. №2 can be solved with Global Security Settings, add the folder where your SWF is as a trusted location: https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Comment: Wizard, Zze, and Quantomworks: I've operated under the impression that cross-domain policies (and as such, the need for crossdomain.xml) are only appropriate when you are actually crossing domains. As Organis notes, both the Flash and the php are on the same domain, and as such, I had assumed there was no need for cross-domain policies. If I am wrong, please feel free to correct me.

With that being said, I will definitely look into that suggestion, Organis. One question though: I plan to allow people to download an offline copy of the Flash and run it - will that cause problems?